# Jquery scroll isn't looping

Tags: jquery, loops, button, scroll, click

I've page with a number of screens on it. There's a **next** and a **previous** button that scrolls the page up or down. Now, here's the problem: Once I hit the last page and hit the **next** button it gives me an error.

I know this is due to the index not being able to go beyond the amount of pages I've made in the first place. I've tried a simple *if* statement like so:

```
if (index > $(".scenes").length) {
$(".scenes").first;
}
```

However, this didn't give me anything at all.

Perhaps I'm not even on the right track, but how do I tell the program to jump back to the first portion of the screen (the top) once the button click scrolls past the last one?

Here's the full code:

```
$(document.body).ready(function() {

var brightness = 60;
var $sceneLength = $('.scenes').length;

$(".scenes").each(function(index) {

    $(this).css({ "background-color": "hsl(200, 100%, " + brightness + "%" + ")" })

    brightness -= 10;

    console.log(index + ": " + $(this).text());
});


$(window).scroll(function() {
    // is in viewport function
    $.fn.isInViewport = function() {
        var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
        var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
        var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

        return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
    }

    $('.scenes').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
            if (index >= $sceneLength / 2) {
                $("h1").css('color', 'white');
            } else {
                $("h1").css('color', 'black');
            }
        }
    })
});

// button scroll function
$("#next").click(function(index) {
    $(".scenes").scrollTop(index);
    $('.scenes').first();
});

var count = 0;
sections = $('.scenes');
scrollPos = function(index) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: sections.eq(index).offset().top
    }, 'slow');

    console.log("count: " + count);
};

$("#next").click(function() {
    count++;
    scrollPos(count);
});

$("#prev").click(function() {
    count--;
    scrollPos(count);
});
});
```

Comment: `count++; if (count>=sections.length) count = 1;` and remove the click event handler that has `$('.scenes').first();`

Comment: I've tried that, but unfortunately I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at scrollPos (init.js:48)" because the count goes beyond the index count.

Comment: I was just looking into that - your `count` and `.eq(index)` need to match - see updated comment `count>=sections.length`

Comment: That did it! It works perfectly with "count" since I've changed ".eq(index)" to ".eq(count)". However, would it be possible to get it to work with index as well?

Comment: Move `sections.eq(index).offset().top` outside the animate, eg `var top = sections.eq(index).offset().top;` `$("body").animate({scrollTop: top})` to reduce issues with closures

Comment: okay nevermind my previous comment. it does the job with "count", so all is fine. Thanks for the help!!